# NHibernate Query Generation

Tags: nhibernate

Some of the NHibernate queries are forming as below, I am just using the NHinernate Map files

select installmen0_.Index as Index1_,installmen0_.accountnumber from Account installmen0_
where installmen0_.accountstatus = 'active'

but I do not have any column called "Index" either in DB table or Map file, Where is NHibernate picking up this column?  Please, sujjest where I might be wrong

Comment: You'll need to provide some of your mapping information for people to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is the default columnname for list indexes. Probably you have mapped in Fluent `Hasmany(...).AsList()` or in xml `<list name="mylist"></list>`. it is used to persist the index of the element in the list. If you dont care in which order they are in the collection then use `Hasmany(...).AsBag()` or `<bag name="mylist"></bag>`